# Link page change not triggering animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am currently been for 2 days now attempting to get react-reveal to work where it does not require a refresh.

Currently what is happening is when I change page via Link it does not trigger some of the components to animate until I refresh the page.

I have read the documentation and it suggests:

> refProp: string If you're using react-reveal component with a custom
>   React component (like a NavLink from React Router) you must specify
>   prop name that would be allow access to the DOM. Typically it would be
>   something like innerRef. By default it is ref. Optional.

So I place in my header.js

```
let anchorRef = React.createRef();

<Link to="/about" innerRef={anchorRef}>
```

Then on the about.js page I am getting undefined when I do

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(props.innerRef);
}
```

This is what I am returning on the page as well as importing the library and etc

```
<Fade bottom ssrReveal distance="150px">
   <p>This is an example</p>
</Fade>
```

All I am after doing is correctly implementing as suggested in the documents however it would seem I am missing something as I am new to using react.

This is the animation library https://www.react-reveal.com/docs/props/

Comment: Are the components you're expecting to animate being unmounted and remounted? If not, [react-reveal will not reset and reanimate them](https://github.com/rnosov/react-reveal/issues/32#issuecomment-421894871). This is the way the author of the library has intended it.

Comment: Yes they are being unmounted and mounted.

Comment: If you wrap the component in a new component and add either `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` methods (class) or a `useEffect` hook logging a message to the console, you can confirm that the dismount and re-mount is occurring? I strongly suspect it isn’t.

Comment: componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount working perfectly when I change between pages. 

The thing is though some animations are working on somethings while others arnt working. It only works correctly if I fully refresh the page but it will work on some things if I switch between pages. Its possible that the calculation of when to trigger is off and may need to be recalled but not sure how exactly.

Comment: Had a further look so if I go from my about page to contact page it seems to start causing the issue higher up on the about page then if I go from about page to partner page which is longer and the issue starts near the end of the about page. But still some things work and others dont. Like I have 6 sections and section 1 will work, section 2 will work, section 3 wont work or part of it and section 4 will work and section 5 wont work.

Comment: Okay, it seems clear that there's something wrong, but also that we don't have an isolated enough case to really help with this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: If I go to a page without it and then to the page with it then it works. But if I got from a page with it to a page with it then it wont work.

Comment: Any idea would be helpful thanks